# What is the full path to the Packages folder for Sublime text 2 on Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, sublimetext

I'm not seeing this question anywhere so I can only assume I'm doing something really stupid but...

What is the full path to the "Packages" folder for Sublime Text 2. I'm looking to install a new theme.

When I go to

> /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/

There is a "Contents" Folder only

Inside that is:

> Frameworks    Info.plist  MacOS       Resources   SharedSupport

Answer (score 366, accepted):

`/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`

Get to it quickly from within Sublime via the menu at `Sublime Text 2... Preferences... Browse Packages`

Comment: It's here on windows 7 C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages

Comment: And on Linux (Ubuntu): ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages

Comment: In addition, the user's library directory is now hidden by default in newer versions of OSX. Run `chflags` `nohidden` `~/Library` in the terminal to reveal them.

Comment: If you are using sublime text 3: ```/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages```

Comment: @RobCowie Major thanks!  Relied on your tip when bumping jshintrc in the old version of Sublime Linter (will link to this answer from https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/c3d52fba323f3eef415265ed2c7582f5fa1e591b)

Answer (score 25):

A useful shortcut from inside Sublime Text:

cmd-shift-P --> Browse Packages
Now open user folder.

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair until now.

Answer (score 15):

### Sublime 2

According to the documentation, in Sublime 2, the package directory is **located under the data directory**. That directory should be on these locations:

- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2
- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2
- Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-2

This information is available [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190716211420/http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory)).

### Sublime 3

For Sublime 3, the locations are the following:

- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3
- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3
- Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-3

This information is available [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702072630/http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory)).

For the **portable version** the documentation above states: "If you’re using the portable version (Windows only), look for Application/Data. Here, Application refers to the directory to which you’ve extracted the compressed portable files and where the executable resides.

Note that the Data directory only exists with that name in the portable version. In full installations, it is one of the locations indicated above."

### Sublime 4

For Sublime 4, when cleanly installed, the locations are the following:

- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text
- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
- Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text

According to [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/side_by_side.html), if Sublime 4 is installed on top of Sublime 3, it uses the ST3 directory. ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211111162300/https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/side_by_side.html))

More documentation about Sublime packages [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/packages.html) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211120215647/https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/packages.html)).

Answer (score 10):

### 1. Solution

[**Open Sublime Text console**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15644431/5951529) → paste in opened field:

```python
sublime.packages_path()
```

→ <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You get result in console output.

---

### 2. Relevance

This answer is relevant for April 2018. In the future, the data of this answer may be obsolete.

---

### 3. Not recommended

I'm not recommended [**@osiris answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158010/5951529). Arguments:

1. In new versions of Sublime Text and/or operating systems (e.g. Sublime Text 4, macOS 14) paths may be changed.
2. It [**doesn't take**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) portable Sublime Text on Windows. In portable Sublime Text on Windows another path of `Packages` folder.
3. It less simple.

---

### 4. Additional link

- [**How to get current … in Sublime Text**](https://kristinita.netlify.com/IT-articles/How-to-get-current-%E2%80%A6-in-Sublime-Text)

Comment: This answer is great and simple and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Don't click on link. Spam. Was reported. Thanks.

Comment: @mbokil, [**fixed**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49967132/revisions). See [**comments for details**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38353#comment82170_38623). I apologize for the inconvenience. Thanks.

Comment: Also try `sublime.installed_packages_path()` for zipped packages

Answer (score 6):

You can browse package folder below method.

1. Use Sublime Text 2 menu : `Preferences\Browse Packages`
2. In Windows 7 : `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages` (equals `%appdata%\Sublime Text 2\Packages`)

Comment: For the second point, `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages` would be even better.