# The shortcut key to open console in Sublime Text 2 does not work

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 (version 2.0.1) on Windows 7, and I haven't installed any plugins for this software. I can use menu to open the console, but I cannot open console via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> shortcut. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have non-English keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried searching this forum yet? http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3

Comment: For everyone stumbling here from Google: On a German Keyboard the shortcut is STRG+ö

Comment: And on a Swedish keyboard it's Ctrl+ö

Comment: I think that it's a problem of OS. When I change my OS, this problem is gone.

Comment: On my UK keyboard doing Ctrl+' works (<-- normal apostrophe) while the backtick command does not.

Comment: Same issue with Sublime Text 3 (Build 3083).

Comment: sometimes the default binding is already being used by the OS or as in your case not very clear what the keys are on your keyboard, one way around it could be defining your own shortcut in the key bindings, something like `{ "keys": ["alt+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} }`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

## Magic Keyboard - US English - Apple

The title itself causes this answer to show up in Google search results for any operating system. So even though the details ask about Windows 7, I am including picture of the shortcut to the Mac because it will save some people a lot of time.
[image]

Comment: Does the answer below from @Samih help? I have the same issue on a UK keyboard with Windows 8. The backtick character is explicitly defined in the preferences as being the shortcut key, but I have to use the regular apostrophe to make it work. I wonder if the quote pairing code is getting in the way? ST forums are down right now, so I can't check...

Comment: Mine is not working using ctrl + ` in a English-UK keyboard

Comment: This has never worked for me on various UK and NZ keyboards but I just discovered that another Windows app was hijacking the shortcut. In this case I was using ConEmu and it was using Ctrl+` to minimise/maximise the app. When I removed it from ConEmu it then worked in Sublime.

Answer (score 26):

### UK Keyboard

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to open the console.

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is pressed, Sublime Text does not receive anything. It is therefore impossible to use this key combination for anything.

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> is pressed, Sublime Text actually receives <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> instead.

### Debuging Keyboard Shortcuts

To see what Sublime Text is receiving, enter `sublime.log_input(True)` at the console.
Obviously change `True` to `False` to turn this off.

Other programs can receive the physical <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> combination so it would seem the issue is within Sublime Text.

Comment: **TL;DR** On a UK keyboard, use `Ctrl+'`. +1

Comment: Debug mode was the key! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

If all else fails, try View > Show Console.

When I run [conemu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) at the time, it seems to grab the ctrl-` and use it for minimize\restore. So I do get a console, just not the Sublime Text one...

Comment: This is the keyboard and language independent way. Works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Solution/Workaround: using preferences options, you can change the key binding.
I've changed mine to ctrl+f1

Comment: How do you do that exactly ? What should i add to my key binding file ?

Comment: In Sublime Text 3, open Preferences > Key Bindings - User, and put this in there: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+f1"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} }`. You can see all the bindings in the Key Bindings - Default

Answer (score 6):

Brazilian Portuguese (ABNT2) shortcut is <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt Gr (right)</kbd>  + <kbd>`</kbd>. It's so complicated that it's worth reassigning the shortcut to something more intuitive as <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (the key on top of the Tab key).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This question is old but I just noticed that on windows 7 for me, ctrl + ' (apostrophe) opens the console not ctrl + ` (backtick) as seems to be documented everywhere.

I am using sublime text 3 though not 2. Also a UK keyboard.

Hope this makes things a little bit simpler for everyone.

Comment: Same here - thanks for this answer! Finally I can open the console instead of hunting in vain for which other app was using the CTRL+` combination!

Comment: I'm on Mac using a US keyboard with a Windows 8.1 virtual machine with Sublime Text 3.  This worked for me.

Comment: It's not just the "documentation" that shows a backtick, it is the character used in the "key bindings". However, the apostrophe is required on some systems (including mine). This would seem to be a bug in Sublime Text(?) - Hamish explains more in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Finnish / Swedish / German / Hungarian layout:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ö</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

On Turkish Keyboard this can be achieved by pressing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

In French KB (Azerty), please use 'ctrl'+ 'ù' combinaison

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut for the console is

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

not

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>

Notice the difference?

Also see here: http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/basic_concepts.html

Comment: I notice that difference. I made a mistake in the question. And I cannot use ctrl + ` for the console.

Comment: Then you need to provide more detail--like your exact version of Sublime (for starters). This definitely works for me on Windows 7 so it's not a problem with ST.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue with Sublime2 - the shortcut for console doesn't work either.

Comment: Very interestingly, it's the opposite for me, perhaps because I am running SublimeText2 in a Windows 7 VM (bootcamp) on my mac but I should reboot into bootcamp and test this theory. Despite my keymap file clearly setting the shortcut as a backtick, the console actually responds to ctrl+' (single quote). No idea how this has happened - and don't ask how long I worked on this before figuring this out....

Answer (score 2):

For Sublime Text 3 on a Windows machine and using an azerty keyboard, CTRL+! is the shortcut that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Portuguese keyboard (Sublime Text 3 in a Mac):

CTRL + <

Answer (score 1):

Spanish keyboard (Sublime 2, Mac)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am using Sublime Text 3 build 3156 on Windows 8.1 system. My keyboard layout is us keyboard style. After enabling `sublime.log_input(True)`, I find that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shows nothing in the sublime text console.

Eventually, I just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to bring up the console. Go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings`, add the following to user key binding setting:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+'"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },
```

Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For UK Keyboard
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>
For Hungarian Keyboard
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ö</kbd>
For Finnish Keyboard
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ö</kbd>
For Swedish Keyboard
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ö</kbd>
For German Keyboard
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ö</kbd>

Comment: is there anything missing from that?

Answer (score 0):

Norwegian keyboard:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> (That's the key between <kbd>+</kbd>and<kbd>Delete</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for user like me on AZERTY and Mac is too change the link to open it.

For this, go to Preferences > Key Bindings - Default 
Dont modify it it's useless it would be refreshed when you lunch Sublime Text.

There do a simple cmd+f and look for "console" 
Once you got it, copy past this and go too the Key Bindings - User just under the previous Key Bindings.

There you can modify it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spanish layout (Qwerty), the shortcut key to open the console (confirmed with Sublime Text 3) is:

CTRL + ñ

Answer (score 0):

Danish keyboard (Mac):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> (Apostrophe? Accent aigu? - the key between <kbd>+</kbd>and<kbd>Backspace</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu on top right corner of sublime there will be a search bar go there and search for console and booom console will be in front of you without any shortcut key :)