# How do I hide the bottom console text output area in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, key-bindings

This is probably really simple, but it's frustrating me so much. I'm using Sublime Text 3. Sometimes my plugins output code to a little window at the bottom like this:

[image]

And I can't hide it no matter what I try. The only way I can get rid of it is by closing the program and opening it again. Does anyone know how to close this?

Comment: I believe it's ctrl + `, or View > Hide Console

Comment: @shennan I had to push it twice, but that seemed to work!

Comment: What OS are you using?  On OSX, simply pressing `esc` closes the console.

Comment: @AGS I'm on Windows 8. I just tried `esc` and yes, that works. So simple, I knew it. Thanks anyway. If only they had a little cross in the corner.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just have to click in the console and simply press <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Or to show and hide the console use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Or toggle menu `View` > `Show/Hide Console`

Comment: Also [note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965877/the-shortcut-key-to-open-console-in-sublime-text-2-does-not-work#comment60676115_16211485): *In Sublime Text 3, open **Preferences > Key Bindings - User**, and put this in there: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+f1"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} }`. You can see all the bindings in the **Key Bindings - Default** [mcissel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882722/mcissel)*"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Esc button is working to remove the side bar(terminal/console bar).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences set: `"show_panel_on_build": false`

And if you want to view the output of the build, press the: `Shift + Esc`