# How to remove a package in sublime text 2

Tags: package, sublimetext2, uninstallation

I would like to remove and/or deactivate the `Emmet` package in Sublime Text 2.

Should I just remove the `Emmet` directory or what is the typical workflow for removal of a package?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

If you installed with package control, search for "Package Control: Remove Package" in the command palette (accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Otherwise you can just remove the Emmet directory.

If you wish to use a custom caption to access commands, create `Default.sublime-commands` in your User folder. Then insert something similar to the following.

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Package Control: Uninstall Package",
        "command": "remove_package"
    }
]
```

Of course, you can customize the command and caption as you see fit.

Comment: Really wish it had the word "uninstall" in there somewhere so I wouldn't need to look it up. After all, it's called `Package Control: Install Package` to add it, so why not uninstall to remove it.

Comment: @JonathanTran I've expanded my answer a bit so you can have that command in the command palette, not that it matters as much now since you know what to look for.

Comment: Works in sublime text 3 too :) Thanks [@skuroda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1852931/skuroda)

Answer (score 22):

Just wanted to add, that after you remove the package in question you might also need to check to see if it's listed in the list of packages in the following area and manually remove its listing:

**Preferences>Package Settings>Package Control>Settings - User**

```
{
    "auto_upgrade_last_run": null,
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "AdvancedNewFile",
        "Emmet",
        "Package Control",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "Sublimerge"
    ]
}
```

In my instance, my trial period for "Sublimerge" had run out and I would get a popup every time I would start Sublime Text 2 saying:

**"The package specified, Sublimerge, is not available"**

I would have to close the event window out before being able to do anything in ST2.

But in my case, even after successfully removing the package through package control, I still received a event window popup message telling me "Sublimerge" wasn't available. This didn't make any sense as I had successfully removed the package.

It wasn't until I found this "auto_upgrade_last_run" file and manually removed the "Sublimerge" entry and saved my edit, did the message go away.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I had to manually remove a package because it was causing Package Control's "remove" dialog to fail, but it kept getting re-installed when I restarted ST. Removing it from the settings file did the trick!

Comment: @Ciwan Go to the [packages folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7866230/532742) and delete the package you don't want.

Comment: You answer helped me to solve this (I had the same message appear on startup for a different package). Just clarifying, in Sublime Text 3, this file is located in `Preferences -> Browse Packages... -> Package Control.sublime-settings`

Answer (score 21):

go to package control by pressing **Ctrl + Shift + p**

type "remove package"

and type your package/plugin to uninstall and remove it

Answer (score 10):

There are several answers, First *IF* you are using **Package Control** simply use Package Control's Remove Package command...

Ctrl+Shift+P

```
Package Control: Remove Package
```

If you installed the package manually, *and* are on a **Windows** machine...have no fear; Just modify the files manually.

First navigate to

```
C:\users\[Name]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text [version]\
```

There will be 4 directories:

1. Installed Packages (Holds the Package Control config file, **ignore**)
2. Packages (Holds Package source)
3. Pristine Packages (Holds the versioning info, **ignore**)
4. Settings (Sublime Setting Info, **ignore**)

First open ..\Packages folder and locate the folder named the same as your package; Delete it.

Secondly, open Sublime and navigate to the **Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings-user**

Third, locate the line where the package name you want to "uninstall"

```
{
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Alignment",
        "All Autocomplete",
        "AngularJS",
        "AutoFileName",
        "BracketHighlighter",
        "Browser Support",
        "Case Conversion",
        "ColorPicker",
        "Emmet",
        "FileDiffs",
        "Format SQL",
        "Git",
        "Github Tools",
        "HTML-CSS-JS Prettify",
        "HTML5",
        "HTMLBeautify",
        "jQuery",
        "JsFormat",
        "JSHint",
        "JsMinifier",
        "LiveReload",
        "LoremIpsum",
        "LoremPixel",
        "Oracle PL SQL",
        "Package Control",
        "Placehold.it Image Tag Generator",
        "Placeholders",
        "Prefixr",
        "Search Stack Overflow",
        "SublimeAStyleFormatter",
        "SublimeCodeIntel",
        "Tag",
        "Theme - Centurion",
        "TortoiseSVN",
        "Zen Tabs"
    ]
}
```

**NOTE** Say the package you are removing is "Zen Tabs", you **MUST** also remove the , after "TortoiseSVN" or it will error.

Thus concludes the easiest way to remove or Install a Sublime Text Package.

Answer (score 4):

Follow below steps-

Step1 - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Step2 - Enter **Disable Package**

Step3 - **enter the package name** that you want to disable and press enter

Successfully removed, if not removed then restart Sublime

Answer (score 2):

Simple steps for remove any package from Sublime as phpfmt, Xdebug etc..

```
1- Go to Sublime menu-> Preference or press Ctrl+Shift+P .
2- Choose -> Remove package option, after you choosing it will display all   packge installed in your sublime, select one of them.
3. After selection it will remove, or for better you can restart your system.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Sublime Text 3

#### Procedure

---

Run Sublime Text.

---

Select **Preferences** → **Package Control**.

Or

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> shortcut for (**Win**, **Linux**) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for (**OS X**).

---

Select Remove Package. <kbd>Package Control: Remove Package</kbd>

---

Start typing **name of the package** you want to remove and **select** it from the list of installed packages.

---

Wait for the *uninstallation* to complete.

Comment: And how to do it manually in Sublime 3? Sublime 3 is crashing when I try to uninstall the Kite plugin.