# How to uninstall a package in sublime text (elaborate)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I have found a link that explains how to add a command to uninstall a package in the package control: [How to remove a package in sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504878/how-to-remove-a-package-in-sublime-text-2).

I need more elaboration on the answer in the link above.

I don't understand what `Default.sublime-commands` is or where to find it.

Also, if I were to try to find the directory where the packages are installed where is it located?

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand about the answer? You open the Command Palette, bring up `Package Control: Remove Package`, select the package you want to remove, and it's gone. You don't need `Default.sublime-commands`, that's only for plugin developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple.

On a Mac open package control and type: shift + cmd + p
Then type: remove package

Should be self-explanatory from there.