# How can I export/import settings of Sublime Text 3 from one PC to another using Windows?

Tags: windows, import, export, settings, sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text 3 in my company and I want to export all the settings, including packages and whatever, to use the same configurations in Sublime Text 3 I have at home. How can I do this?

PS.: I use Windows 8

Answer (score 52):

The best way is to sync the `User` directory, there are multiple available ways to do this - dropbox, git and manual ways.

Installed packages are registered in `Package Control.sublime-settings`, which is located in the user folder as well, thus, it does not require you to sync anything besides that. A pretty good guide to syncing can be found [here](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing).

You also may wish to check out [this package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublimall).

Comment: I honestly haven't had to do this, but my feeling is that the entire `AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3` directory should be backed up. I personally have it set up as a Git repository. The User data is most critical, but what about packages that are manually installed and configured, for instance? If they're not on Package Control, then you'll have to go through the entire manual installation process again if only the User directory is sync-ed. Also, for packages that you manually tweak (that you must alter the code, because there's no built in config), that's again not covered by the User dir.

Comment: @aliteralmind you can install all the packages which you alter in the User directory as well, that's even the right way to do

Comment: On linux user config is saved in ~/.config/sublime-text-{2,3}/

Comment: Where is the user director on a Mac?

Comment: @mangocaptain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808452/what-is-the-full-path-to-the-packages-folder-for-sublime-text-2-on-mac-os-lion

Comment: For anyone looking for the location, mine was at : C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\

Answer (score 33):

For me (Windows installation) transferring all the content from old installation - AppData\Roaming\Subime Text 3, to new installation - AppData\Roaming\Subime Text 3, does the job. All the packages and UI settings are transferred and are working correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't do that 'cross Operating System. Because package versions may differ from OS to OS.

Comment: this just worked! Also, I've setup my two PCs very similarly :)

Answer (score 15):

None of the manual efforts are needed now (I think). Both sublime text (ver 3) and visual studio code (if anyone cares) have extensions that do this for us.

For VS Code -
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

For ST3 - 
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sync%20Settings

With a few clicks like generating token and configuration, one should be able to easily port the settings from any machine (Win, OSX, Linux) to any machine.

Answer (score 11):

You can try this plugin [PackageSync](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageSync). It can package your settings and packages into a zip or 7z file, then, you can import them on another machine.

Comment: As of july 2019 this is the easiest way for package and settings export / import: creates a zip file in computer A, you move zip file to computer B, load zip file in computer B, done.

Comment: This works for me and very easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside an easy way to locate the 'User' or 'Sublime text {2/3/etc}' folder regardless of OS is to:

Open go-to-anything and just type: 'us'

From the available options select 'Preferences: Package Control Settings - User’ to open that file.

Right click on the file and make the selection to open the containing folder (Mac: reveal in finder)

Navigate back up to the parent folder Sublime Text 3 (or whatever version number you are on)

Copying this folder and replacing the Sublime Text 3 folder in a fresh Sublime install with this one should install all packages and replicate any other settings you have.

Answer (score 0):

[source](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-it-possible-to-sync-settings-preferences/6975/2)

"If you want to sync settings across machines, the best way to do so is to just sync the Packages\User\ folder. This contains all customized settings, and if you are using Package Control, it includes a list of all installed packages. If Package Control sees that an installed package is not present on the machine, it will automatically install it the next time Sublime Text starts."

PS: if I am not mistaken the author of this post is the key developer of sublime.