# packagecontrol.io is not working. How can I install package control and install packages?

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

When I am using below code to install Package Control on Sublime Text, I got URL Error

**Consolde Code**

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '2915d1851351e5ee549c20394736b442' + '8bc59f460fa1548d1514676163dafc88'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

**Error**

```
>> import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '2915d1851351e5ee549c20394736b442' + '8bc59f460fa1548d1514676163dafc88'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 1248, in do_open
  File "./http/client.py", line 1065, in request
  File "./http/client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
  File "./http/client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
  File "./http/client.py", line 906, in _send_output
  File "./http/client.py", line 844, in send
  File "./http/client.py", line 822, in connect
  File "./socket.py", line 435, in create_connection
  File "./socket.py", line 426, in create_connection
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 487, in _open
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 1268, in http_open
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 1251, in do_open
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

After getting this error I checked packageconreol.io website. But it not opened. Then I checked the status of the website using http://www.websitenotworking.com/. It reply, the website is not working. In this stage how can I install Package control and installing package?.

Comment: I am currently having problems using the Package Control in Sublime. It seems that their servers are down (https://packagecontrol.io/ is not responding). This is probably the reason. Hopefully it will be back online soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a website being down, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

The website packagecontrol.io is hosted by Linode in Atlanta. Which right now has faced a very sophisticated DDoS attack and as such selectively blocking their connectivity as a precaution. I think they will be up in a day or two so right now just wait and keep checking the website. You can check whats happening at Linode at [status.linode.com](http://status.linode.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's been down for couple of days. The site is up jus now and down again. wanted this badly to install TernJS

Comment: True! https://twitter.com/peteretelej/status/682963582951243776

There seems to be a backup_channel https://twitter.com/mikechabot_/status/683160682154573824

Answer (score 1):

Package Control is not the only way to install packages in Sublime Text.
You can can either:

- Download the package and uncompress it in the package folder
- Git clone the package source in the package folder

The location of the package folder varies according to the O.S.
You can find it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808452/what-is-the-full-path-to-the-packages-folder-for-sublime-text-2-on-mac-os-lion)